# Soundcloud API - Unshare track from user

Tags: javascript, api, soundcloud

I'm having trouble trying to share/unshare a private track to a user, here's my script, hopefully someone can tell me where i'm going wrong:

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
  SC.initialize({
      client_id: 'myclientid',
      redirect_uri: 'http://localhost/callback.html'
  });

  $('#scConnect').click(function(){
      SC.connect(function() {
          SC.delete('/tracks/123456/shared-to/users/7891011', function(me, error){  
  });
      });
  });
```

});

In the above example, I would like to remove user 7891011 from accessing track 123456

I followed the API documentation which states:

Methods: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE
Path: /tracks/{id}/shared-to/users (users who have access to the track)

At a guess I don't think I think i've specified the user id correctly.

Any help appreciated

Claire